# Recursive function acting on variadic class template parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, recursive-datastructures, recursive-templates

So I have the following (cut down) classes:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename... B>
struct ComponentTupleAccessor: 
    public ComponentArray<A>, 
    public ComponentTupleAccessor<B...> 
{
    ComponentTupleAccessor(const uint32_t capacity): 
        ComponentArray<A>(capacity), 
        ComponentTupleAccessor<B...>(capacity) 
    {}
};
```

```cpp
template <typename A>
struct ComponentTupleAccessor<A>: 
    public ComponentArray<A> 
{
    ComponentTupleAccessor<A>(const uint32_t capacity): 
        ComponentArray<A>(capacity) 
    {}
};
```

```cpp
template <typename A, typename ...B>
class ComponentTuple {
    ComponentTupleAccessor<A, B...> m_Components;
    uint32_t m_Capacity;

public:
    ComponentTuple(const RB32u capacity): 
        m_Capacity{capacity}, 
        m_Components(capacity) 
    {}

    template <typename S, typename ...T>
    void pop_back() {
        m_Components.Component<S>::pop_back();
        pop_back<T...>();
    }

    template <typename S>
    void pop_back() {
        m_Components.Component<S>::pop_back();
    }

    void pop_back() {
        pop_back<A, B...>();
    }
};
```

The `ComponentArray` class is basically a wrapper around a vector that holds a bunch of components of a particular type.

The `ComponentBlockTupleAccessor` class more or less emulates a cut down version of std::tuple where the any number of unique types of `ComponentArray` can be inherited into the class `ComponentTuple` using the variadic templates.

The `pop_back` function in `ComponentTuple` is designed to recursively `pop_back` an element off each of the `ComponentArray`s.

Outside of the `ComponentTuple` class I'd like to be able to simply call something like `compTupleInstance.pop_back()` and all `ComponentArray`'s should have their last elements removed.

I get a compile error "call of overloaded ‘pop_back()’ is ambiguous" pop_back();

I can't seem to figure out a combination of the A, B (pack), S, and T (pack) template parameters that gives me the functionality I need. What am I missing here?

Edit: Here is a simple usage scenario:

```cpp
// ComponentTuple contains an int and a float ComponentArray with capacity 8.
ComponentTuple<int, float> dut(8);

// Push a set of new components to the ComponentArrays.
// This function has a similar structure to that of pop_back.
dut.push_back({8}, {3.141f});
// Another one
dut.push_back({4}, {2.718f});

// Remove the last element from all of the ComponentArrays.
dut.pop_back();
```

ComponentTuple template parameters will always be unique types, and there will always be greater than one.

Comment: If T argument pack is empty, you have 2 identical push_back()

Comment: I think the issue is that your `pop_back` functions do not take any arguments; this means they end up having the same signature.  Perhaps you can elaborate a little one what the functionality is that you are aiming for.  Add some code that shows how you intend to invoke these methods?

Comment: @Willem Yeah you are right. I have a push_back function of a similar structure, and it doesn't have any problems because the function signature is always unambiguous. How do I maintain the recursive template functionality without at least one non-variadic parameter though?

Answer (score 0):

A copy from the question:

```cpp
    template <typename S, typename ...T>  // T can be empty
    void pop_back() {
        m_Components.Component<S>::pop_back();
        pop_back<T...>();
    }

    template <typename S>
    void pop_back() {
        m_Components.Component<S>::pop_back();
    }
```

If I invoke `pop_back<A>()` I have `S = A`. But, am I calling the first method with `T` empty, or am I calling the second method?

Answer (score 0):

The core issue: `template <typename S, typename ... T>` and `template <typename S>` look equally good for the compiler when there is only one template argument (the pack can be empty). It cannot make a decision on which overload to use.

Solution: You can use fold expression (c++17 or above).

```cpp
void pop_back() {
    (m_Components.ComponentArray<A>::pop_back(), ... , m_Components.ComponentArray<B>::pop_back());
}
```

...Also the code breaks (even with the fold expression above) if used like this:
`ComponentTuple<int, int, double>` (ambiguous base class).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, the ambiguity between `<typename S>` and `<typename S, typename... T>` seems obvious now that you've pointed it out. It seems it's just not possible to do it the way I was trying to, for that reason.

I ended up using a `if constexpr` to test if the recursion is at the last Type, so I can terminate the recursion at that point. I like this even better since in the non templated `pop_back` there is no risk of giving template parameters that weren't used in declaring the class. e.g.

```cpp
ComponentTuple<int, float> dut(8);

push_back<Banana, char>; // Not int, float so should cause compile error.
```

Using the `constexpr` method, I can privatise the `pop_back` function (see `pop_back_` below), and only expose the no-params version so that the method can only be called in the correct way:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename ...B>
class ComponentTuple {
    ComponentTupleAccessor<A, B...> m_Components;
    uint32_t m_Capacity;

    template <typename S, typename... T>
    void pop_back_() {
        m_Components.ComponentBlock<S>::pop_back();

        if constexpr (sizeof...(T) > 0) {
            pop_back_<T...>();
        }
    }

public:
    ComponentTuple(const RB32u capacity): 
        m_Capacity{capacity}, 
        m_Components(capacity) 
    {}

    void pop_back() {
        pop_back_<A, B...>();
    }
};
```

Obviously I need to make sure I'm using at least c++17 to use `if constexpr`.